# How to give type for new Set typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have new Set and want to put it in props or in argument of function.

```
 const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = React.useState(new Set([]));
```

How can i write types for that?

For example, I have a function, that will in arguments get new Set

```
const onSelect = (selectedIds // here i want to write type, it is argument from newSet) => {
    const newSelectedIds = new Set(selectedIds);

    if ( selectedIds.has(selectedId) ) {
      newSelectedIds.delete(selectedId);
    } else {
      newSelectedIds.add(selectedId);
    }
    setSelectedIds(newSelectedIds);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Set` class is generic. You can pass the type of the elements like this:

```
const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = React.useState(new Set<string>([]))
```

Since it's a class, it can also be used as a type:

```
const onSelect = (selectedIds: Set<string>) => {...}
```